# PlacePicker deprecated

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I have followed a tutorial on implementing Google Maps API using Android Studio and had my progress halted when I found out that Place Picker is depreciated. As a result, my app crashes on opening.

From the tutorial, I have implemented the MapView, zoom function, center function and location update request, and I am having problems with implementing location search.

```
    private fun loadPlacePicker() { //creates new builder for an intent to start the Place Picker UI
        val builder = PlacePicker.IntentBuilder()

        try {
            startActivityForResult(builder.build(this@MapsActivity), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST)
        } catch (e: GooglePlayServicesRepairableException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

I believe the expected results would be implementing a Floating Action Bar which can be used to search for a location. On the code, PlacePicker is strkethrough-ed and displays a message: " 'PlacePicker' is depreciated. Depreciated in Java".

The following error is shown, and I have no idea what this means:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 9675
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_maps: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_maps: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3121)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:81)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1935)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7116)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:925)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_maps: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_maps: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_maps: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:830)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1021)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:976)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:674)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:549)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:496)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.myapplication.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.kt:153)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7698)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7687)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3096)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:81)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1935)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7116)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:925)
E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-hlq7WMD7jhn1Gt1eYykECw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-hlq7WMD7jhn1Gt1eYykECw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-hlq7WMD7jhn1Gt1eYykECw==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-hlq7WMD7jhn1Gt1eYykECw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-hlq7WMD7jhn1Gt1eYykECw==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-hlq7WMD7jhn1Gt1eYykECw==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-hlq7WMD7jhn1Gt1eYykECw==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-hlq7WMD7jhn1Gt1eYykECw==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-hlq7WMD7jhn1Gt1eYykECw==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-hlq7WMD7jhn1Gt1eYykECw==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-hlq7WMD7jhn1Gt1eYykECw==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-hlq7WMD7jhn1Gt1eYykECw==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-hlq7WMD7jhn1Gt1eYykECw==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.myapplication-hlq7WMD7jhn1Gt1eYykECw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 26 more
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.example.myapplication-hlq7WMD7jhn1Gt1eYykECw==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:365)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:107)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:80)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:444)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:403)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:126)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:101)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:74)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:87)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:116)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:114)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoaderWithSharedLibraries(ApplicationLoaders.java:60)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:861)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:958)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1196)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2462)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2454)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1778)
                ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the documentation:

> The Place Picker (Android, iOS) is deprecated as of January 29, 2019.
>   This feature will be turned off on July 29, 2019, and will no longer
>   be available after that date. To continue using the Place Picker with
>   Places SDK for iOS v.2.7.0 through the deprecation period, do NOT
>   disable the Places SDK for iOS.

Please note that only the users of Place Picker before January 29, 2019 are the ones that can continue using the Place Picker until July 29, 2019, this is because the Place Picker can only be used if the **Places SDK for iOS/Android** is enabled in your [GCP Console](https://console.cloud.google.com), The **Places SDK for iOS/Android** is not visible to the new users now. New users will now need to enable Places API in order to use the mobile SDKs wherein the Place Picker is now not available.

Google is currently conducting a review on what drives the users to use the Place Picker, if you are interested, you may add your answer in the form mentioned in this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/128304760) in the Issue Tracker.